# Annoymous class OnClick Listener Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I wrote a new activity in android studio. The error as so:

> 'Anonymous class derived from OnClickListener' must either be
>   declared abstract or implement abstract method 'onClick(View)' in
>   'OnClickListener'Class 'Anonymous class derived from OnClickListener'
>   must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method
>   'onClick(View)' in 'OnClickListener'

Here is my current application code:

```
package com.example.win.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewDebug;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

 public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText first,second;
    TextView Ans;
    Button add;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        first =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        second=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Ans=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView6);
        add=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
        add.setOnClickListener(new *** View.OnClickListener() ***
//Error occurs at the *** part

        {
         public void onclick(View view){
               final String n1=first.getText().toString();
                final String n2=first.getText().toString();
                int a=Integer.parseInt(n1);
                int b=Integer.parseInt(n2);
                int c=a+b;
                Ans.setText(String.valueOf(c));
            }
        });

    }
  }
//The error occurs at the *** part in the above code
```

Answer (score 4):

Your method signature has a typo, it should look like this:

```
new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
       // Do whatever here.
    }
}
```

Comment: IT WORKS... THANK YOU Soo much

Comment: No problem, for future reference though please make sure you exhaust common issues such as typos before posting questions on SO.